# SharePoint DateTime Format

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have SharePoint 2010 calendar and I am opening it as DataFormwebpart in SharePoint Designer and I noticed EndDate as follows:
xsl:value-of select="@EndDate"/
and the result is 2012-03-15T14:30:00Z

How can I modify the xsl:value-of select="@EndDate"/ to Show DateTime as follows 
2012-03-15 9:30 AM

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to parse the value with XSL and XPath. Check out these links, they should get you started:

XSL if:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_if.asp

XPath transform():
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

And some related SE posts: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268116/how-can-i-do-string-operations-in-xslt 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569523/can-an-xslt-parse-a-string-of-text

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can get the desired result with the following but just missing the time part, I want 9:00 AM instead of 14:00<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="no" select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@EventDate), 2057, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm')" /> result is 12/03/2012 14:00

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/workdog/archive/2007/02/08/105858.aspx

Comment: Try and use 1033 instead of 2057, since AM/PM probably is not used in your location (2057) it will not parse it with AM/PM.

Comment: Try using this format string: 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm P' HH = hours (24 hour clock) hh = hours (12 hour clock) P = AM/PM marker Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-format-dateTime (see section 16.5.1)

Comment: Thanks guys, the following is working, but AM/PM part is not working even I added P in the end but no luck. Can you plz let me know any alternative. select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@EventDate), 2057, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm')"  result is 12/03/2012 02:00

Comment: Do you want 12-03-2012 02:00AM?

Comment: certainly not the correct method but will work if you use <xsl:choose><xsl:when test=" [24 hour value] = [the 12 hour]"> [the 12 hour value] AM </xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>[the 12 hour value] PM